# Typo on /tags/synonyms

Tags: bug, status-completed, spelling

The HTML shows

```
Users with more than  2500 reputation and a total answer score of 5or more on the tag, can
```

So there's two spaces before 2500 (which is acceptable) and no space between `5` and `or` so.

Comment: I don't see the error:  you need fiveor mores to edit the tag wiki...

Comment: @James I don't know if you're being funny or ...

Comment: I was trying to make a joke.  Sometimes they aren't funny.  Sorry.  :-)

Comment: @James ok, I was just checking. I think I see the joke you were trying to make, but wasn't sure if I was overreading it. #DamnYouNonVerbalCluesThatAreRequiredForCommunication !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just fixed the missing space ... thanks for reporting ... will be deployed later today